# Updating .aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, ftp

I've inherited an ASP.NET project that uses a single Default.aspx file in the `public_html` root to do most of the work.

The changes I'm making are minor, but I can't seem to get them to stick. If I edit the Default.aspx file, the server will still serve the old version. Creating a new .aspx file will initially compile it and run it, but then it's stuck in its "original request" form.

I thought .aspx files were subject to "dynamic recompilation" if they were changed, but this isn't triggered in my case. I've tried updating the Web.config file but is has no effect.

I'm not using Visual Studio for this, yet. I'd like to be able to just edit and update the files, if possible (the changes are very minor and I don't have ready access to a Windows machine). The only access I have to the server is through FTP.

Comment: public_html is an uncommon place to place these aspx pages. Are you sure you are editing the right files? If it's an IIS box, the website is *usually* put under `c:\inetpub\wwwroot `

Comment: Is there any .NET output caching directives at the start of the page?

Comment: Are the changes you make saving at all? If not it would seem like you might have a permissions issue, if they are then are you sure the page you are editing is the one that the server is using live and not just a copy?

Comment: I am sure I'm editing the right files; Copying an .aspx file, changing something, and accessing the new URL will compile and display the changes.

Comment: @freefaller Not to my knowledge. There's a simple `<%@ Page Language="C#" %>` at the top of the .aspx file. No changes are honored when requesting the edited file – whether it's HTML or embedded C#.

Comment: You mention about copy the default.aspx, editing that and it shows... now you have copied and edited, what happens if you edit that second file again? I'm wondering if you have some strange caching somewhere else (like a firewall, proxy or even your browser)

Comment: Whenever I copy a file, edit it, and request it, it runs with the new code at request time. Making changes and re-requesting the file has no effect – the new changes are not reflected. I've tried requesting the page using different browsers and even with my cell phone (cellular network) and it's no different.

Comment: What happens if you give a random query-string value each time? i.e. `default.aspx?random=1234`

Comment: It makes no difference. I've even tried removing the file and accessing it, but it still gets served in its "original" state.

Comment: Even when you change the random value!? (i.e. don't keep putting `random=1234` but change the 1234 to different values) You have a doozy there my friend, I honestly don't know what is going on, but my guess is that something is happening with caching on the server (which I presume you have no control over, as you mention FTP access in your comments below)

Comment: @Icarus just clarifying, its not uncommon at all. `inetpub\wwwroot` is just the default location - even I don't use it all in any of my (dedicated) servers. If you don't have a dedicated server, it can be in any location the hosting provider deems fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the issue was with my host, who aggressively cache stuff. I have to do a "restart" from inside their control panel to have the changes reflected.

The host is Loopia.se, in case anyone else is using them. Use "Omstart av ASP.NET-applikationer" from inside the Customer Zone to restart things.

(Yes, I do feel kind of silly now)

Comment: I presume they are caching the FTP files, and not the actual output of the ASPX page?  If it's the latter, I would definitely look at a different host.

Comment: This is likely - particularly if you are using any cloud service. Common workarounds - delete (not copy/replace) the file and upload a new one (kills the cached copy). Other "more intrusive" options: open web.config and save it, if your provider has an "application restart" option, etc.

Comment: They are "caching" the compiled code from the first time you access the file. Even after removing the .aspx-file, I could still access it from my browser and have it run its "original" code. Messing with web.config did nothing.

Answer (score 1):

If the site has previously been 'published' in visual studio as pre-compiled and not-updatable, then changing the aspx files will result in no change:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.80).aspx

In this case everything will have been pre-compiled into DLL's, and the aspx pages are just there as hooks for the .net runtime.

Comment: I believe this is relevant. However, should there then not be DLL files in the folder? The ONLY files in the folder are Web.config and Default.aspx. There are no subdirectories. If the DLL files are not placed in the same location as the other things, where are they? There is no location (accessible by the FTP account) where I can find any such files.

Comment: @vicvicvic Usually the DLLs are in a `/bin` folder in the root of the application directory (So, "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Your App Name\bin\")

Comment: Hmm... There's no such folder (accessible from the FTP account) that I can see...